# In rails how to get content from a json in another url

Tags: ruby-on-rails, json, ajax, rest

Hello i making a project in rails where i have an api that returns a json, and i wanted to get the contents of this json and show in my view how i could do it in an elegant way. I did it in ajax, but I would like to know if there is any way to do this in rails only.

Thank you for your attention, and I need to say that English is not my main language

I used this code below to generically supply what I need

```
<script language="JavaScript">
$(document).ready(function(){

$('#people').click(function(){

    $.ajax({
        url: "http://localhost:3000/people.json",
        //force to handle it as text
        dataType: "text",
        success: function(data) {

            //data downloaded so we call parseJSON function 
            //and pass downloaded data
            var json = $.parseJSON(data);
            //now json variable contains data in json format
            //let's display a few items

            for (var i=0;i<json.length;++i)
            {
                $('#response').append('<div class="name">'+ json[i].name +  json[i].age + json[i].gender + json[i].lonlat + json[i].name +'</>');
            }
        }
    });

});

});
</script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [Rails UJS](https://github.com/rails/jquery-ujs):

```
<%= link_to "Something", something_path, id: "people", data: { remote: true, type: 'json' } %>
```

Rails UJS binds an event handler to links and forms with the `data-remote="true"` attribute. The handler by default tries to get a JS format response - which we override by setting  `data-type="json"`.

Rails UJS fires [custom events](https://github.com/rails/jquery-ujs/wiki/ajax) on the originating node which we can tap into:

```
// Put this in application.js or somewhere else in app/assets/javascripts
// not inline. 
$(document).on('ajax:success', '#people', function(data, status){
  var $el = $('#response');

  $.each(data, function(p){
     $el.append(
       '<div class="name">'+ p.name + p.age + p.gender + p.lonlat + p.name +'</div>'
     );
  }); 
});
```

Another way to do it is by creating a `js.erb` template but thats a even worse of a mess.

Comment: Thank you, I'll do what you told me. :)